# How to make Vertical StackView subviews (same specific heights) start from TOP, Swift?

Tags: swift, uistackview, clean-architecture

I'm creating a vertical UIStackView where arranged subviews will start from top. Subviews quantity will be 5 at most. Here are my expectation, reality and code. Any Idea?

**Expectation**

[image]

**Current situation**

[image]

**Code**

```
var homeVStack: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.alignment = .top
    stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
    stackView.spacing = 20
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return stackView
}()

private func loadData() {
    if let homeFormList = data?.homeTeamForm {
        for homeForm in homeFormList {
            let teamFormView = SimpleScoreView()
            teamFormView.teamForm = homeForm
            teamFormView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
            teamFormView.backgroundColor = .yellow
            homeVStack.addArrangedSubview(teamFormView)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are explicitly setting the Height of the subviews:

```
teamFormView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

So, do NOT give your stackView a Bottom anchor or Height constraint.

Here's a quick example...

**SimpleScoreView** -- view with a centered label:

```
class SimpleScoreView: UIView {
    let scoreLabel = UILabel()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        self.backgroundColor = .yellow
        scoreLabel.textAlignment = .center
        scoreLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scoreLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        addSubview(scoreLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scoreLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            scoreLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }
}
```

**Basic View Controller** -- each tap will add another "Score View":

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var homeVStack: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        // these two are not needed
        //stackView.alignment = .top
        //stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
        stackView.spacing = 20
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return stackView
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(homeVStack)
        
        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // constrain stack view Top / Leading / Trailing
            homeVStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            homeVStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            homeVStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
        ])
        
        loadData()
    }

    // for this example, loadData() will add one new
    //  SimpleScoreView each time it's called
    private func loadData() {
        let v = SimpleScoreView()
        v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        v.scoreLabel.text = "\(homeVStack.arrangedSubviews.count + 1)"
        homeVStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        loadData()
    }
    
}
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use empty view like UIView() on your last arranged view. It should be made larger than its intrinsic size.

```swift
var homeVStack: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.alignment = .fill // default is .fill
    stackView.distribution = .fill
    stackView.spacing = 20
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return stackView
}()

private func loadData() {
    if let homeFormList = data?.homeTeamForm {
        for homeForm in homeFormList {
            let teamFormView = SimpleScoreView()
            teamFormView.teamForm = homeForm
            teamFormView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
            teamFormView.backgroundColor = .yellow
            homeVStack.addArrangedSubview(teamFormView)
        }
    }

    homeVStack.addArrangedSubview(UIView()) // Important
}
```

Above code make your stack view layout like this. UIView should be stretched than SimpleScoreView's intrinsic size

[image]

Current Situation image said homeVStacks constraints are top, bot, leading and trailing to its superview with equal spacing so second  SimpleScoreView is on bottom.

You can choice two options

1. You should make spacing with another UI like transparent UIView for stretched instead of SimpleScoreView bottom layout.
2. Remove stack view's bottom constraint to root view and make height by contents(arranged view)

Comment: I don't wanna put empty view. Because the subviews count are not always be two.. will become three next weekend and so on..

Comment: Many item also fine because you can set hugging priority and compression priority low on UIView then it should be compressed with many items

Answer (score -1):

what are the constraints of homeVStack? make it center horizontally and vertically in super View.

Comment: homeVStacks constraints are top, bot, leading and trailing to its superview. Nothing special.

Comment: remove top and bottom constraints

Comment: @ZinWinHtet add homeVStacks in storyboard with .alignment = .fill, and .distribution = .fillEqually, remove just bottom constraints and add items in stack programmatically as you did will behave as you expect.

Comment: you answer seems correct. But I will need a heightconstraint if bottom one have to remove.

Comment: @ZinWinHtet calculate it based on screen height "UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - any constant" and divide it by number of teams and set it 
teamFormView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

Comment: @ZinWinHtet another suggestion make  **.alignment = .fill**, **.distribution = fill** and add an empty view at the bottom 'homeVStack.addArrangedSubview(UIView())' it works when I try it

Comment: I bottom constraints and put heightAnchor instead. It's working now. So I learned that Vstacks need specific heights to arrange itself.